# Android recyclerview defauilitemanimator change duration

Tags: android, animation, android-recyclerview

I use recyclerview for dynamic list. After insert and removed items recyclerview performs a sharp update. I use DefaultItemAnimator for more beautiful update I list.

```
optionList2.itemAnimator = DefaultItemAnimator()
```

I would like to try to increase the delay for the animation. Can you tell me how to do this?

Answer (score 5):

Use set(Change/Add/Move/Remove)Duration method:

```
optionList2.itemAnimator = DefaultItemAnimator().apply {
                changeDuration = 250
                addDuration  = 250
                moveDuration = 250
                removeDuration = 250
            }
```